# Rails 3 run_callbacks with parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

i'm playing with run_callbacks and had a problem. Can somebody help me out?

```
## loveable.rb
module Loveable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    define_callbacks :love
  end

  def loved_by!(lover)
    run_callbacks :love do
      do_love(lover)
    end
  end

  def do_love(lover)
    ...implementation goes here...
  end
end

## product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Loveable

  set_callback :after, :love, :after_love

  def after_love
     ## How to get lover here??
  end
end
```

I need "lover" user in after_love method. How could I achieved that?

For now I using instance variable but don't like the solution.

```
## loveable.rb
def loved_by!(lover)
  @lover = lover
  run_callbacks...
end

## product.rb
def after_love
  @lover.do_something
end
```

Any better idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use an instance variable :)

The only serious concern you have with using instance variables in modules is the risk that the variable names used in the module will clash with names in the class itself or other included modules.  If you use a sufficiently obscure name, say `@_xxx_loveble_lover`, that should effectively minimise the risk.

From your code it appears that `lover` is an attribute associated with each object, so instance variables are the best device for this.